# not standard splitting

Tags: python

I have string value like:

**a='[-sfdfj aidjf -dugs jfdsif -usda [[s dfdsf sdf]]]'**

I want to transform "a" into dictionary: the strings with preceding "-" character should be keys and what goes after the space should be values of the key preceding it.
If we are working with "a", then what I want is the resulting dictionary like:

**dict_a={'-sfdfj': 'aidjf', '-dugs': 'jfdsif', '-usda': '[[s dfdsf sdf]]'}**

This would be simple if not the last value('[[s dfdsf sdf]]'), it contains the spaces. Otherwise I would just strip the external brackets and split the "a", then convert the resulting list into dict_a, but alas the reality is not on my side.
Even if I get the list like:

**list_a=['-sfdfj', 'aidjf', '-dugs', 'jfdsif', '-usda', '[[s dfdsf sdf]']**

this would be enough.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string by '-' and then add the '-' back.

```
a = '[-sfdfj aidjf -dugs jfdsif -usda [[s dfdsf sdf]]]'
a = a[1:-1]    # get ride of the start and end []
sections = a.split('-')
dict_a = {}
for s in sections:
    s = s.strip()
    if len(s) == 0:
        continue
    key_value = s.split(' ')   # split key value by space
    key = '-' + key_value[0]         # the first element is key
    value = ' '.join(key_value[1:])    # the lefe are value
    dict_a[key] = value
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I wanted :).

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you a way to go about it.
Strip the quotes and the outer brackets. Then split the string using spaces. Iterate over the list obtained and check for any opening brackets. Keep a count of the number of opening brackets, join all the list items as a string with spaces between each such item until you encounter an equal number of closing brackets. The remaining items remain as is. You could try implementing it. If you face any issues, I'll help you with the code.

@chong's answer is a neater way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> dict(re.findall('(-\S+) ([^-]+)', a[:-1].replace(' -', '-')))
{'-sfdfj': 'aidjf', '-dugs': 'jfdsif', '-usda': '[[s dfdsf sdf]]'}
```

Using @ChongTang's idea:

```
>>> dict(('-' + b).strip().split(maxsplit=1) for b in a[1:-1].split('-') if b)
{'-sfdfj': 'aidjf', '-dugs': 'jfdsif', '-usda': '[[s dfdsf sdf]]'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re

a='[-sfdfj aidjf -dugs jfdsif -usda [[s dfdsf sdf]]]'

pattern_key=re.compile(r'(?P<key>-\S+)\s+')
pattern_val=re.compile(r' (?P<val>[^-].*?)( -|\Z)')
d={}

matches=pattern_key.finditer(a)
matches1=pattern_val.finditer(a)

for m,n in zip(matches, matches1):  
    d[m.group('key')]= n.group('val')   

print d
```